# Vaadin-Grid Multiline Cell Polymer

Tags: polymer, vaadin-grid, vaadin-elements

I am looking to have cells which have a fixed width, but can expand in height as to fit multiple lines. However I have not been able to find any native solutions to this.

Answer (score 1):

The row heights are fixed `<vaadin-grid>` 1.x, so I don't any way to achieve this, unfortunately.

There is a prerelease version of the 2.0 version which supports variable row heights based on content.

Comment: How can I access the 2.0 version?

Comment: `bower install vaadin-grid#2.0.0-pre.1` See https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/releases/tag/v2.0.0-pre.1 for details